# What was the inspiration for the diminishing of the elves, and separation of their realm from the world?

Tags: history-of, elves, mythology

An important theme in Tolkien lore is the separation of Valinor from Middle-earth, and the subsequent diminishing of the Elves.

In more recent novels, these themes appear again, for example, in *The Elves* by Bernhard Hennen, which features

> The complete separation of the elves' realm from the human world, with only one elf remaining for a time.

I am assuming later fantasy using this theme got the inspiration from Tolkien, but where did Tolkien get this theme from? Is it something that exists in European folklore/myths? I am not asking about fairies living a separate realm, but asking about sundering the connection to said realm, or if the connection is still there, then at least something trying to explain why there are fewer elves/fairies/etc. today than in the past.

Comment: Given that Arda is our world, and we don't see Elves nowadays, it is clear that they *have* diminished, surely?

Comment: @DanielRoseman But is it made explicit in myths WHY?

Comment: The sentiment that the (imagined) past was somehow better than the dreary present was not exactly invented by Tolkien. You will find the same in any 80s music Youtube channel , where people will claim that this was the time of incredible music and impeccable hair-dos, which is hardly less phantastic than the idea that elves and orcs once roamed the earth.

Comment: The folklore does not say that the elves go away, but they are indeed rare. As are other magical creatures

Comment: The ultimate inspiration is that there aren't Fey wandering around openly in real life, compared to the worlds of Folklore. Therefore Folklore includes a reason why they've gone away / been separated from us.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this exists in European folklore.  Katherine Briggs documents many cases of people saying that there used to be fairies, but they died or went away, and that was the end of it.

The folklorists who collected these tales noted that these stories were told side by side with tales of a continuing fairy presence.  Then, folklore is seldom noted for its consistency.

Comment: Elves and fairies aren't necessarily the same but either way do you have any evidence to back this up?

Comment: “folklore is seldom noted for its consistency” — later folklore tellers had clearly never heard any folklore! Bad telling!